# How to project the result of WordNet words in a corpus

Tags: java, netbeans-7, wordnet

Actually my problem is that I would like to extract from a document words that give wordnet Result in order to take only the words that exist in the document. But the result is still empty I think it is because of words are different formats.

How should I do to change the words in the document in their basic forms.

For example if I have the word "car" and I would found its hypernonyms through wordnet then I only keep the words found in the document how I should do this?

Answer (score 0):

Stanford has a lemmatizer written in Java that I have actually used for my information retrieval course, but it doesn't work right out of the box.  You can [download it here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#Download), and I suggest you read the documentation before using it.

Now all you have to do is feed the lemmatizer the word before you index it. Words that reduce to the same lemma (root form) should index to the same place in your dictionary.

Comment: first of all think you so much for your answer but it still not clear for me. I don't know if you have undrestand clearly my question.
I want to know how to project wordNet result on a document(is a string format). In order to find which words in wordNet result are existing in the document. I woul to manipulate it in a java class

Comment: @Hela A word could have hundreds of hypernyms. If you attempt to search the corpus for all of them, the program will be slow. Lemmatize the words while you build the corpus, then also lemmatize the search term. That way, you only have one term to search for. This is also why modern information retrieval systems use inverted indices. In an inverted index, two words that belong to the same lemma will index to the same location. WordNet takes one word and expands to many results. You need to reduce many results to one word (the exact opposite). For that reason, I suggested a lemmatizer.

Comment: Yes I untrestand now your suggestion and I will try it. Morever have you any idea how to extract relations part-of and cause-off from Wordnet: I have two concepts and I wont to know the kind of relations between them can I do it trought WordNet. else have you any idea please how to do it?? thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: I would ask a new question that is specifically about that topic. Make sure you read the How To Ask guidelines before posting, to avoid getting a lot of downvotes. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask